# How to prevent misusing my Account details

Tags: income-tax, india, identity-theft

One of my friend know my account details like pan no and all, and now he started doing some business with that and I am getting income tax notices for that how I will block him from using my details and how to handle this situation please give proper advice

Answer (score 2):

This is more legal and less personal finance question. You should immediately lodge a police complaint mentioning that some persons are using your PAN card details for activities not authorized by you.

In the meantime also engage the services of a CA and reply back to income tax authorities. Do not ignore the notice.